# How to implement a very precise polarizer inside a fiber-based setup?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, laser, polarization, fiber-optics

A tricky question: I need to use polarizers with a ~5 arcmin precision inside a PM fiber-based system. What are some (hopefully cost-effective) ways of achieving this? The setup works with linear polarization.

Comment: what do standard suppliers offer, and how does or doesn't that help you with your application?

Comment: 2 options using standard supplies that I can see: (1) a motorized paddle polarization controller followed by an inline polarizer or (2) integrating a free space setup (collimator > polarizer > collimator). I guess #2 would require an additional complication of aligning the PM fiber's fast axis with the new polarization state. And I'm probably missing other options that more experienced people here have used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on the purpose but you can use a QWP & Liquid crystal configuration as a controllable polarisation rotator (look it up). Instead of the liquid crystal you could use any birifringent material, even a QWP that you "twist"